# How to get a substring from a string in mysql

Tags: mysql

Sorry if this has already been asked but I wasn't able to find an answer that can help with my issue.

I need to extract the name of a country from a string where the location of the string could be anywhere.

Example data strings

```
1) Location - Living in: United States, Age: 18+, (and so on)
2) Location: United Kingdom, Excluded Connections: France,
3) Age: 65+, Language: english, Living in: United States,
```

So for those examples, I would just need

```
1) United States
2) United Kingdom
3) United States
```

Its all comma separated but I can't seem to get it to find the value I need.

My current set up

```
Select bio, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.`targeting`,'Location: ',-1),',',1) AS country
from table1
```

Also sorry for the formatting! Having trouble formatting this correctly.

Comment: Based on the format you have, you would need to search for specific strings, since the 'Location:'  won't work with the 3 examples you provided.

Comment: Are Living in: and Location: the only prefixes?

Comment: Could you have a table of allowed country names then join that table using a LIKE operator to this field? Otherwise you are in for some gnarly string parsing, searching, and endless edge cases.

Comment: @SEarle1986 The prefixes to the data I need are the following: "Location - Living in", "Living in: ", "Location: " The problem is that those prefixes could be scattered anywhere in the string with other variables surrounding them on either side like age or excluded connection.

Comment: @JNevill Unfortunately no since the data I need is only within those given strings and Excluded Connections: could have other country names to that would be allowed.

Comment: This is really hard to do in plain SQL. There are some regular expression UDF libraries that would probably be helpful, you should search for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query should work (I've tested on given sample data and it's working properly):

Also, I've assumed `a.targeting` is the column that contains these strings as per your query.

```
SELECT 
 (case when LOCATE("Location - Living in", a.targeting) > 0
            then SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.targeting,"Location - Living in: ",-1),",",1)
       when LOCATE("Location:", a.targeting) > 0
            then SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.targeting,"Location:",-1),",",1)
       when LOCATE("Living in:", a.targeting) > 0
            then SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.targeting,"Living in:",-1),",",1)
  end) AS country;
```

Hope it helps!